# Is there a way to re-set the first batchfile argument?

Tags: batch-file

I'd like to do this:

```
set %1="html"
```

But it doesnt work, I get back:

> '"html"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your code will set the variable, the name of which is the first argument to the procedure, to "html". Please explain what you intended to do in context - show us a little more of your code than one statement in isolation and explain what you intend as parameters and what your result should be by `edit`ing your question.

Comment: I suppose you should rethink to use another solution

Answer (score 2):

`%1` is not a variable that you assign with SET. It represents the first argument to a called batch script (`test.bat arg1` or `call test.bat arg1`) or subroutine (`call :subroutine arg1`).

If you want to change the value of %1, then you do so where you make the CALL, not within the CALLed script/routine.

There are situations where a line `set %1=value` is used. You might have a routine that computes a value and then stores the result in a variable whose name is retrieved from the first argument to the routine.

But if the routine is called without an argument, then the line expands to `set =value`, which generates the error that you are getting.

If you are working with the `%1` argument, and conditionally want to "change the value" within the script, then you must transfer the value to an environment variable, and work with the variable from that point on.

A trivial example would be to provide a default value if the argument is not passed:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "arg1=%~1"
if not defined arg1 set "arg1=default"
REM From now on you never refer to `%1` but use `%arg1%` instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

```
@ECHO OFF
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET 1="html"
echo %1%
echo !1!
PAUSE
```

Executing this code with parameter `abc` will return

```
abc
html
```

Obviously you need `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` to be able to "overwrite" %1. However, this won't actually overwrite %1 but make it's updated value accessable. AFAIK there is no way to really overwrite it. There is only one workaround I can think of:

Call your file with "html" as second parameter and use `SHIFT`:

```
ECHO %1
SHIFT
ECHO %1
```

Executing this code with params X and html (yourfile.bat X html) will print:

> X
>
> html